# Is it ok to have vertex count in cylindrical objects not equial to 8, 16, 32, etc?

Tags: vertices, geometry

For example, I have cylinder with 33 vertices instead of 32 (see attached image). To my mind there is nothing wrong with this. But may be I am wrong? Just wanted to ask blender guru about it, guys.
[image: 33 Vertices]

Comment: Hi, not a guru but, nothing wrong, as long you don't mind about symmetry of course... If you wished 33.3 vertices, maybe _that_ would be weird....

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps one thing that might cause problems is *Grid Fill*. Odd vertex number leads to triangles and ugly grid.

Comment: Thank you, good friends! I suppose now, that cylinder based on 40-vertices circle will do just fine.